# Blackscreen with GPU fans at max speed

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, fan, black-screen-of-death

**Sympton:**

- During some games, after 2-20 Minutes a black screen appears
- CS2, CS:GO, Anno 1800 suffer from blackscreen
- Did not get a single black screen playing hours of COD
- Sound is still playing in background when black screen appears
- GPU fans turn instantly to full speed

**What did I try to solve the problem?**

- Clean reinstall of Windows 11
- Installed all necessary drivers from MSI (which is my mainboards manufacturer)
- Installed current NVIDIA driver
- Replaced 850W PSU with brand new 1000W PSU
- Checked Windows Event Viewer for any hints, none found
- Executed a mem test without any errors (https://www.memtest86.com/)

**My specs:**

- 12GB MSI GeForce RTX 3080 VENTUS 3X PLUS OC LHR GDDR6X 3xDP 1.4a 1xHDMI 2.1
- 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11700K @ 3.60GHz (16 CPUs), ~3.6GHz
- Windows 11 Home 64-bit (10.0, Build 22621) (22621.ni_release.220506-1250)
- MSI B560M Pro-VDH Wifi (B560,S1200,mATX,Intel) (7D18-001R)
- be quiet! Straight Power 11 Platinum (1000 W)

**Do you have any ideas on:**

- what could be the reason for the black screen?
- what can I do to further troubleshoot the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Interesting and weird... No problems with COD that requires DirectX 12. The problem seems to be with older and/or less demanding games (DirectX 11 or older)

Answer (score 0):

When you try replicate the black screen, have a temperature monitor on to see what is happening - my first thought was the power supply not providing enough power but you said you already replaced that.

If the temperature is normal - The only other thing I can think of is the driver crashing - try a few version of the driver too. (DDU the current one).

Something else to try is to use a try the GPU in a different PC to rule out any hardware.

The last resort I would even consider is reflashing the bios on the GPU - but i would not even consider this without consulting with the graphics card manufacturer first.

Comment: It's not what you think one way or the other